# Which is preferable: redundant HTML layouts, or unnecessary JavaScript execution?

Tags: javascript, html, performance, jekyll

I'm using Jekyll to build a website that is styled consistently across all pages. The majority of pages are styled using a layout file called `default.html`. However, on one particular page I need to make use of JavaScript that is called via `a rel` tags. In all other respects, the formatting of this page is identical to its siblings.

In this scenario, which is preferable:

1. Creating a redundant layout file which is almost identical to `default.html`, but contains the necessary JavaScript, or;
2. Putting the JavaScript inside `default.html` and performing useless execution on every other page?

In terms of performance -- in the simple example where there is only one page that requires the JavaScript, I assume the first alternative to be the lesser of two evils, as you only make one extra HTTP request as opposed to many, many useless JavaScript calls. However, this won't always be the case with increased scale.

So, what is the best way -- performance-wise or stylistically -- to handle the execution of JavaScript on a single page managed using markdown templating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give the content of your extra page a variable that is true if the Javascript must be included.

```
---
layout: default.html
incScript: true
---
```

And then, in your `default.html`, use Liquid to conditionally include the script:

```
{% if page.incScript %}
  ... include script here
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Fantastic! I knew there must be a way to handle this scenario by design. If my understanding of Liquid is correct, the conditionals are handled during the build process, and thus there is no performance impact upon the client.

Comment: Yes, Liquid is handled offline, by Jekyll, during the build process. No performance impact upon the client whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

I think first, because then you 'll not get any errors where your code is not needed.
so put the javascript in a file like "yourfile.js" and call it with `<script src="/yourfile,js"></script>`

That should be best